# iOS6, Segue: UIViewController loses data while moving on navigation stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I built a hierarchy of viewControllers and in my storyboard scene I need to move two nibs ahead. The problem is that after I return to controller, it seems to lose the id that is important to retrieve required data from DB. One nib ahead OK, but after two nibs NO.

Also, after returning neither `-viewWillAppear` nor `-viewDidLoad` get fired. Thank you in advance.

I checked if segue really feeds the right data. The final nib gets right id. So, problem isn't  data lost while segue.

CODE:
First nib receives data from main nib. `viewWillAppear` fetches data from DB and fills up the labels etc.

Navigation begins here.

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDublicates"])
{
    DublicatesViewController *controller=(DublicatesViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
    // controller is tableViewController
    controller.typeID=self.typeID;
    controller.nominalID=self.nominalID;
    controller.regionID=self.regionID;
    controller.subCountryID=self.subCountryID;
    KMObj *obj=[self.arr objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dublicates | KM%@",obj.kmRef];
}
```

Second nib. NSLog reveals that data is OK. Moving to final nib

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toCreateDublicate"])
{
    NewDublicateViewController *controller=(NewDublicateViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
    controller.typeID=self.typeID;
    controller.subCountryID=self.subCountryID;
    controller.nominalID=self.nominalID;
    controller.regionID=self.regionID;
    controller.numberOfExistingDublicates=[_arr count];
}
```

The method that fires in final controller

```
-(void)back {

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: show the code for the setup and the navigation change

Comment: Popping a view controller off the navigation stack will not cause any lifecycle methods to be called on the underlying view controller, so that behavior is correct. To help your further, we need code.

Comment: Code added. Hope it will clear the situation.

Comment: After returning back I get my labels blank.

Comment: You're using the term nib wrongly -- a nib is a file, I think you mean controller or scene. Are all of these controllers in one storyboard? Also, are these two segues the only segues you have in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, probably. I call scene nibs. I have more segues, but they work correct.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? If I understand correctly, you're going from NewDublicateViewController to DublicateViewController with popViewControllerAnimated, is that correct? And you have some labels in that controller that are empty when you come back?

Comment: KMController -> DublicatesViewController -> NewDublicateViewController. After coming back the labels on KMController getting blank.

Comment: How are you coming back? Your question says that the (void)back method is in the final controller, and popViewControllerAnimated will take you back only one controller. So how are you getting back to KMController?

Comment: same -back meth exists on all controllers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30710/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-nathan)

Comment: Are you resetting the id in the third controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1